# Adding datetime column with time in seconds column of a csv file using shell

Tags: bash, shell, sed

I have a csv file having many rows and its header is:

```
   DateTime,CallEndTime,KeywordTagTexts,TotalDuration
```

Position of the the header keys changes, therefore I have calculated positions using sed

```
duration=$(sed -n $'1s/,/\\\n/gp' rawfile.csv | grep -nx 'TotalDuration' | cut -d: -f1);
callend=$(sed -n $'1s/,/\\\n/gp' rawfile.csv | grep -nx 'CallEndTime' | cut -d: -f1);
callstart=$(sed -n $'1s/,/\\\n/gp' rawfile.csv | grep -nx 'DateTime' | cut -d: -f1);
```

The value in DateTime is "2018-12-18 18:36:55" in date time format and TotalDuration is in seconds.

I want to add the value DateTime + TotalDuration to CallEndTime,

Answer (score 0):

The idea is to first convert to epoch time (seconds since 1970-01-01 00:00:00 UTC), then add the duration and finally convert back to previous notation:

```
DateTime_epoch_time=$(date +%s -d $DateTime) 
CallEndTime_epoch_time=$(("$DateTime_epoch_time" + $TotalDuration))
CallEndTime=$(date '+%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S' -d @$CallEndTime_epoch_time)
```

Or in one line:

```
date '+%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S' -d @$(($(date +%s -d "$DateTime") + $TotalDuration))
```

More details on date formats manipulation in [man date](https://linux.die.net/man/1/date)

Comment: no need to convert to epoch time. `date '+%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S' -d "(${DateTime})  + ${TotalDuration} seconds"` will work

Comment: Thx. Did not know date STRING format was that powerful.

Answer (score 0):

For example I have taken Total duration values as 1000

Below is sample format of example which i took which is sample as you posted apart from last column

2018-12-18 18:36:55,callendtime,KeywordTagTexts,1000

Please comment for any corrections or changes

Step1

Converting colum1(datetime in seconds)

```
datetime_in_seconds=$(date -d "`awk -F "," '{print $1}' example.txt`" +%s)
```

step2

Adding Column1(datetime)  and last column(Total duration) To calculate CallEndTime

```
k=$((datetime_in_seconds + duration_in_seconds))
```

Now printing value in orginal format

Final command

```
awk -F "," -v k="$k"  'OFS=","{$2=$2"="k;print $0}' example.txt
```

Output

```
2018-12-18 18:36:55,callendtime=1545188015,KeywordTagTexts,1000
```